# Rails 3. Why is Capistrano adding an index.html file to my public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Ok, there are lots of issues with my deployment, but im going to focus on one for now.

when i deployed, i forgot to add setup to the command `cap deploy:set` so instead i typed `cap deploy`. i dont know if it has anything to do with it.

so what happens every time i deploy, there is an index.html file in my public folder. whyyyy?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, fixed it with the following command

`git commit -a -m 'delete public/index.html file'`